# FourierParameters default differs from documentation?

Tags: fourier-analysis

Running Mathematica 11.2.0 I see in the documentation that FourierParameters defaults to {0,1}, yet when I try a Fourier transform with the default options, vs those values explicitly, I get different results.  It looks like the defaults actually appear to be {0,-2Pi} :

```
FourierTransform[Sinc[t], t, \[Omega]] 
FourierTransform[Sinc[t], t, \[Omega], FourierParameters -> {0, 1}]
FourierTransform[Sinc[t], t, \[Omega], FourierParameters -> {0, -2 Pi}]
```

These give respectively

$$\frac{1}{2} \pi  \text{sgn}(2 \pi  \omega +1)+\frac{1}{2} \pi  \text{sgn}(1-2 \pi  \omega )$$

$$\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{\frac{\pi }{2}} (\text{sgn}(1-\omega )+\text{sgn}(\omega +1))$$

$$\frac{1}{2} \pi  \text{sgn}(2 \pi  \omega +1)+\frac{1}{2} \pi  \text{sgn}(1-2 \pi  \omega )$$

Is FourierParameters configurable somehow, and is Mathematica finding a default FourierParameters value that differs from the documentation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check the default options of any symbol with `Options`. For me, `Options[FourierTransform]` outputs:

> {Assumptions :> $Assumptions, GenerateConditions -> False, 
>    FourierParameters -> {0, 1}}

Which coincides with the documentation. Furthermore, the output I get without parameters matches the results for `FourierParameters -> {0, 1}`.

If you `Unprotect[FourierTransform]`, you can change the default options simply by setting them, e.g.:

```
Unprotect[FourierTransform];
Options[FourierTransform] = {Assumptions :> $Assumptions, GenerateConditions -> False, FourierParameters -> {0, -2 Pi}};
```

However, this is difficult to actually recommend.

Answer (score 2):

Something is weird with your setup:

```
FourierTransform[Sinc[t], t, w]
FourierTransform[Sinc[t], t, w, FourierParameters -> {0, 1}]
FourierTransform[Sinc[t], t, w, FourierParameters -> {0, -2 Pi}]

1/2 Sqrt[\[Pi]/2] (Sign[1 - w] + Sign[1 + w])
1/2 Sqrt[\[Pi]/2] (Sign[1 - w] + Sign[1 + w])
1/2 \[Pi] Sign[1 - 2 \[Pi] w] + 1/2 \[Pi] Sign[1 + 2 \[Pi] w]
```

Maybe you have some lingering definitions that conflict with the transform calculation.

Comment: It seems that a one time execution of ClearAll[ \[Omega] ] resolved this issue, as I did not see it when w was used.  Curiously, before that ClearAll, even after restarting Mathematica I still saw the difference from the default with {0,1}.